# How to set an existing Linux environment variable to a Chef attribute?

Tags: chef-infra

On my Linux node, when an I do:

```
echo $WORK_DIR
```

It outputs something like: `/home/exampleuser/work`

I have a chef cookbook where, I want to create an attribute that is set to whatever `$WORK_DIR` is.

Example:

```
default[example_cookbook][workdir] = path of whatever the $WORK_DIR system variable is?
```

How could I achieve this in Ruby/Chef? The value of `$WORK_DIR` could change from environment to environment, so I want the value of that to be set as the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables can be accessed in [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/ENV.html) and in Chef by using `ENV` hash.

You could assign the value of `$WORK_DIR` to an attribute as below:

```ruby
default['example_cookbook']['workdir'] = ENV['WORK_DIR']
```

Comment: Thank you. What about the case where an environmental variable is set only after part of your recipe has run?

Comment: That would be tricky. `chef-client` goes though [several stages](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview/#the-chef-infra-client-run), and node attributes are "built" before converging the node (execution phase). Any attribute changes after this phase will not be reflected in the run. Please see link for detailed explanation.