# Knife bootstrap pass environment variable

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I want to pass environment variables to the remote system I am bootstrapping but I am unable to do so.

Usecase:
Recipes which I am using needs artifactory username and password to download the artifacts.

Example :  `curl -u ${ARTIFACTORY_USER}:${ARTIFACTORY_PASS} -X GET ${Artifact URL}`

but I am not able to pass the values.

Knife bootstrap command which I am using is

`knife bootstrap ${IPAddress} -o winrm -x ${username} -P ${password} -N ${Chef_Node} --policy-group ${Policy_Group_Name} --policy-name ${PolicyFile_Name}`

I tried sending the variable in knife.rb and config.rb file in the below format but didn't work.

```
knife[:ARTIFACTORY_USER] = ENV['ARTIFACTORY_USER']
knife[:ARTIFACTORY_PASS] = ENV['ARTIFACTORY_PASS']
```

Comment: Are you running `curl` command inside recipe? It will be good if you can update the question and show relevant code from recipe. That said, using [attributes from env vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63634194/how-to-set-an-existing-linux-environment-variable-to-a-chef-attribute/63634870#63634870), or databags will be a better approach.